# Angular Router Event

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights

Tried to use some applicationinsights service found in github https://github.com/sandorfr/ngx-app-insights-sample/issues/1 but it seems the service is encountering error

Tried to import some event as recommended in stackoverflow

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ResolveEnd, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
const environment = {
    production: false,
    appInsights: {
        instrumentationKey: 'sampleinstrumentationkey'
    }
};
@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService {

    private routerSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        if (environment.appInsights && environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey) {
            if (AppInsights.downloadAndSetup) {
                AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(environment.appInsights);
            }
        }
        router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            const activatedComponent = this.getActivatedComponent(router.routerState.snapshot.root);
            if (activatedComponent) {
                this.logPageView(`${activatedComponent.name} ${this.getRouteTemplate(router.routerState.snapshot.root)}`, event.urlAfterRedirects);
            }
        });
    }

    setAuthenticatedUserId(userId: string): void {
        AppInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext(userId);
    }

    private getActivatedComponent(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {

        if (snapshot.firstChild) {
            return this.getActivatedComponent(snapshot.firstChild);
        }

        return snapshot.component;
    }

    private getRouteTemplate(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
        let path = '';
        if (snapshot.routeConfig) {
            path += snapshot.routeConfig.path;
        }

        if (snapshot.firstChild) {
            return path + this.getRouteTemplate(snapshot.firstChild);
        }

        return path;
    }

    private AddGlobalProperties(properties?: { [key: string]: string }): { [key: string]: string } {
        if (!properties) {
            properties = {};
        }

        //add your custom properties such as app version

        return properties;
    }

    public logPageView(
        name: string,
        url?: string,
        properties?: { [key: string]: string },
        measurements?: { [key: string]: number },
        duration?: number) {

        AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, this.AddGlobalProperties(properties), measurements, duration);
    }

    public logEvent(name: string, properties?: { [key: string]: string }, measurements?: { [key: string]: number }) {
        AppInsights.trackEvent(name, this.AddGlobalProperties(properties), measurements);
    }

    public logError(error: Error, properties?: { [key: string]: string }, measurements?: { [key: string]: number }) {
        AppInsights.trackException(error, undefined, this.AddGlobalProperties(properties), measurements);
    }
}
```

the code is working but in a certain amount of time i encounter the following error

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./ClientApp/app/components/services/app-insights/app-insights.service.ts:30:21
>
> TS2345: Argument of type '(event: NavigationEnd) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: Event) => void) |
>   undefined'.   Type '(event: NavigationEnd) => void' is not assignable
>   to type '(value: Event) => void'.
>       Types of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible.
>         Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'NavigationEnd'.
>           Type 'RouterEvent' is not assignable to type 'NavigationEnd'.
>             Property 'urlAfterRedirects' is missing in type 'RouterEvent'.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that telling Typescript that the filter operator will ensure that event is of type NavigationEnd will solve that error:

```js
        router.events.pipe(
            filter((event: Event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
```

You will need to import those types:

```js
import { Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```